# handle component mounted for change position

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a toggle (hide/show) component (like to tooltip) and want catch mounted event to check and change position (from left or from right) if out of screen.
I try `@onMount @onMounted @mounted @mount` it's not work. I found event `@vnodeMounted` but don't know right or no and if I use `@vnodeMounted` target will be null and I can't get rendered
element width\height\position.

```
<Tooltip v-if="show" class="absolute top-0 left-full" @vnodeMounted="changePositionIfOutScreen"></Tooltip>

function changePositionIfOutScreen(event){
    event.target // null
}
```

Comment: Trigger a custom event from inside the Tooltip component during mounted()

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `VnodeMounted` callback is an object, whereas the mounted DOM element is under `el`:

```js
function changePositionIfOutScreen({ el }){
    //e.g.:
    el.clientWidth
}
```